# how to automate hover on all points of highchart horizontally?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, highcharts

I need to put play button on top of highchart. On click of the button i need to hover on all points of chart one by one, so that i looks like all points of chart are being visited one by one.

Comment: Please consider posting related code.

Comment: You can use point.setState method to hover/unhover. The rest will js timeouts/intervals - see example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/exxrbyt9/)

Comment: your idea is really helpful and worked. will improve code for need and share soon.